# Работает только в python idle

Tags: python, lxml, urllib

Скрипт работает только в IDLE(Встроенная ide для python).
Если скрипт запускать вручную , то он вылетает с ошибкой . 
Исходная страница в windows-1251

```
import urllib.request as ulib
import lxml.html as htm

def Maximal():
    page = ulib.urlopen("http://www.bash.im/").read()
    print(str(page.decode('cp1251')))
    input()
Maximal()
```

Ошибка :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1022: character maps to <undefined>
```

upr:Python 3.2 sorry , забылся =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы запускаете из терминала виндовс то в нем кодировка cp866(вроде), если из под линукса то там utf8.

При выводе сообщений в терминале нужно учитывать его кодировку.
А вообще желательно делать так , это должна быть первая строка файла:

для линукса :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

для виндовса :

```
# -*- coding: cp866 -*-
```

ЗЫ

А еще вы используете python 3.X , желательно упоминать о таких тонкостях :)

**upd:**
ошибка вылазит при попытке декода страници из 1251 в то что у вас по умолчанию

**upd2:**

вот так будет на pythone 2.7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener({}) # если так не сделать будет тоже что и у тебя
f = opener.open("http://www.bash.im/")
a = f.read()
print a[:200].decode('cp1251') # [:200] - показывает первые 200 символов
```

вывод консоли :

```
user@user:~/project$ python f1_test.py
<!doctype html>
<html id="godtier">
<head>
    <title>Цитатник Рунета</title>

    <meta charset="windows-1251" />

    <link href="http://s.bash.org.ru/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta
```

Comment: Да python 3.2

Comment: а какая ОС ?

Comment: О_О так ведь баш уже давно переехал. Неужто на сайте стили со старым адресом :)

Comment: я даже внимания как то не обратил )))